# weird php sub() and add() function changing my variable

Tags: php, datetime, variables, dateinterval

something very weird is happening when using `sub()` and `add()` functions in different `variables` since it changes other variables from before

Here is an example:

```
echo $current_uf->date; // prints 2020-04-09 

$x = new DateTime($current_uf->date);
$data["yesterday_uf_date"] = $x->sub(new DateInterval('P1D'));
$data["tomorrow_uf_date"] = $x->add(new DateInterval('P1D'));

echo $data['yesterday_uf_date']->format('Y-m-d'); // prints 2020-04-09
echo $data['tomorrow_uf_date']->format('Y-m-d'); // prints 2020-04-09
```

for both variables prints `2020-04-09` since i was expecting to receive `2020-04-08 and 2020-04-10` ... at first i thought i was doing something wrong in the code but then when i deleted tomorrow line of code i got `2020-04-08`

```
$x = new DateTime($current_uf->date);
$data["yesterday_uf_date"] = $x->sub(new DateInterval('P1D'));

echo $data['yesterday_uf_date']->format('Y-m-d'); // prints 2020-04-08
```

So i'm not sure why when i use de add() function in another variable to save it there, it changes subtracting and then adding, therefor i end up getting the same date.

I tried to search something about this but could find anything related. can someone explain/help solving this issue?

Comment: `sub()` and `add()` modify the object in place, they don't return new objects.

Comment: So both array elements refer to the same date as `$x`.

Comment: The docs mention the return value is a reference to itself to support chaining functions https://www.php.net/manual/en/datetime.sub.php and the top rated comment is exactly your scenario too